# Alternative way to have an SQL query of Group By

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have two tables with columns:

```
Table: Employee
1.empName
2.empNo
3.deptId

Table: Department

1.deptId
2.deptName
```

I have written a query-

> ```
> select count(*) as total, d.deptName, e.empName from Employee e JOIN Department d on e.deptid = d.deptid
> Group By d.deptName, e.empName;
> ```

The above query works fine, but I wanted to learn How can I write a query to avoid including a `e.empName` in `Group By` clause, and still select it?

Is there any alternative way to accomplish this.

Comment: I don't understand the goal of this query, what do you want to count? If you want to count the employees of a department, why do you select their name?

Comment: which DBMS are you using? it can't be all 3 different ones at the same time.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This query doesn't need a `Group by` given the columns you are selecting.

Answer (score 1):

IF you are grouping something then you need to specify aggregate for all columns . If you are not doing so then it must be in group by for those columns.

In your case if you want to achieve it than you have to specify any aggregate function to e.empName column.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the `min` or `max` of the name but this assumes that you only have one employee per department.

```
select count(*) as total, d.deptName, MIN(e.empName) from Employee e JOIN Department d on e.deptid = d.deptid
Group By d.deptName;
```

Basically if you're grouping by department you'll only get one row per department so if you've got several rows of employees per department you can't include it without some sort of transition, be careful with this, it could lead to some strange and dangerous results.